# Accessing localhost (127.0.0.1) when off line

Tags: firefox, localhost

I keep a mirror of my Web site on my laptop, and use the laptop Web server at *localhost* to check changes.  That works fine if I am on line, but if my laptop is off line, Firefox refuses to send an HTTP request to *localhost*.

Is there a way to force Firefox to talk to *localhost* when off line?

Answer (score 2):

Click on File... and check to see if "Work Offline" is checked. If it is, uncheck it and it will properly interact with the localhost interface.

Comment: This will most definitely be the issue!

Comment: This does not really answer the question.  This tells how to turn off "offline" mode, but "offline" really makes no sense when dealing with localhost.  localhost is always online.  Firefox should be able to contact localhost even when it's considered offline for other sites.  Turning offline off will enable localhost but disable other offline apps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have proxy server configured? If `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` are not in the exception list the browser will send these requests to the proxy too. If your system is offline, FF cannot reach the proxy server and cannot reach localhost through the proxy server.

Comment: I doubt a proxy would be able to somehow redirect to localhost when online. So, if the proxy is configured wrong, then http://localhost should also not work when *online* -- but it seems it does?

Comment: You are right. The localhost for the proxy is the proxy itself. :-)
Okay, my answer is wrong completely. :-)